# get value from an array of objects based on value of attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
   Identifiers: [
     {
     Identifier: {
      Source: "TEST",
      Symbol: "123456",
     }
    },
     {
      Identifier: {
       Source: "TEST2",
       Symbol: "345678"
      }
    },
    {
      Identifier: {
       Source: "TEST3",
       Symbol: "456789"
     }
   ]
```

I need to retrieve the value of the Symbol key for Source: "TEST3" from the array. I only have access to TEST3. What would be the best way to retrieve the val

Comment: Use `find()` method to get the object

Comment: `Identifiers.find(el => el['Identifier']['Source'] === 'TEST3')['Identifier']['Symbol']` using find is best, just be careful with your key selection.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `Identifier` object returned like this:

```js
let input = [{Identifier:{Source:"TEST",Symbol:"123456",}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST2",Symbol:"345678"}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST3",Symbol:"456789"}}]
   
let { Identifier: { Symbol } } = input.find(a => a.Identifier.Source === "TEST3");
console.log(Symbol)
```

If there is a possibility that the identifier doesn't exist for a `Source`, use a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

```
let { Identifier: { Symbol } = {} } = input.find(a => a.Identifier.Source === "TEST333") || {};
```

If you don't want to use destructuring:

```js
let input = [{Identifier:{Source:"TEST",Symbol:"123456",}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST2",Symbol:"345678"}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST3",Symbol:"456789"}}]

let found = input.find(a => a.Identifier.Source === "TEST3");
let source = found && found.Identifier.Source;

console.log(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11) `_.flow()` and `_.partialRight()` to create a function that uses `_.find()` to get the object by the `Source` property, and then extracts the `Symbol` using `_.get()` (`_.get()` will return `undefined` if the item is not found).

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, find, get } = _

const symbolBySource = src => flow(
  pr(find, ['Identifier.Source', src]),
  pr(get, 'Identifier.Symbol')
)

const identifiers = [{Identifier:{Source:"TEST",Symbol:"123456",}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST2",Symbol:"345678"}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST3",Symbol:"456789"}}]

const result = symbolBySource('TEST3')(identifiers)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the terser [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) version:

```js
const { flow, find, get } = _

const symbolBySource = src => flow(
  find(['Identifier.Source', src]),
  get('Identifier.Symbol')
)

const identifiers = [{Identifier:{Source:"TEST",Symbol:"123456",}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST2",Symbol:"345678"}},{Identifier:{Source:"TEST3",Symbol:"456789"}}]

const result = symbolBySource('TEST3')(identifiers)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```